# Should accepts_nested_attributes_for also be setting up the association correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

Given some kind of `Thing`:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  include CustomFieldable
  #...
end
```

Which can have custom field values attached to it:

```
module CustomFieldable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :custom_field_values, as: :custom_fieldable, dependent: :destroy
    validates_associated :custom_field_values
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :custom_field_values
  end
end
```

And where custom field values are basically just a string value (at least for now) with a reference to their owner:

```
class CustomFieldValue < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :custom_fieldable, polymorphic: true, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :custom_field, dependent: :destroy

  validates_presence_of :custom_fieldable
  validates_presence_of :custom_field
  validates_presence_of :string_value
end
```

And to the custom field, which is just a wrapper around a name:

```
class CustomField < ApplicationRecord
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

When I initialise the `Thing` with a hash:

```
"thing"=>{
  //...other stuff...
  "custom_field_values_attributes"=>{
    "0"=>{
      "custom_field_id"=>"1",
      "string_value"=>"value 1"
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect ActiveRecord to set up the association from the `CustomFieldValue` back to the `Thing`. But it looks like it is not, because I get a validation error:

> There were problems with the following fields:
>
> - Custom field values custom fieldable can't be blank
> - Custom field values is invalid

So it's like when I use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, the parent association is not set up. Is that expected behaviour?

**Update #1:**

Controller logic for permitting the fields looks like this:

```
class ThingController < ApplicationController

  def thing_params(action)
    common_params = [ omitting common stuff... ]
    params.fetch(:licence).permit(*common_params,
                                  custom_field_values_attributes: [
                                    :custom_field_id, :string_value ])
  end
end
```

**Update #2:**

If I write two tests for the model, I can see the same thing happening.

**Fails:**

```
  test "adding a custom field value on construction via nested attributes" do
    thing = Thing.new custom_field_values_attributes: [
      { custom_field_id: custom_fields(:environment).id,
        string_value: 'Testing' }
    ]
    assert_attribute_not_invalid thing, :custom_field_values
    assert_equal 'Testing', thing.custom_field_values[0].string_value
  end
```

**Passes:**

```
  test "adding a custom field value via nested attributes" do
    thing = things(:one)
    thing.update_attributes custom_field_values_attributes: [
      { custom_field_id: custom_fields(:environment).id,
        string_value: 'Testing' }
    ]
    assert_valid thing
    assert_equal 'Testing', thing.custom_field_values[0].string_value
  end
```

So it's like, if the record isn't saved yet, Rails doesn't set up the nested models correctly, but if it's already saved, they get set up correctly.

Comment: What about strong params in your thing_controller? I am wondering if you need to add custom_field_values_attributes to thing_params.

Comment: Added it to the description. It seems it's already there. Well, I did say in the question that it happens when passing a known hash as well. So I can see the hash being sent in, it just seems like Rails isn't setting things up for me. I'll see if I can write a model test to prove it anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I tried something on a whim. Changed this:

```
    has_many :custom_field_values, as: :custom_fieldable, dependent: :destroy
```

To this:

```
    has_many :custom_field_values, as: :custom_fieldable, inverse_of: :custom_fieldable, dependent: :destroy
```

So it seems that Rails cannot guess the inverse relationship for polymorphic associations - even though I was already forced to tell it this using `:as`. Specifying it twice works fine.

Answer (score 0):

With the code given, I would say every thing works fine. You create a `Thing` object and add multiple `CustomFieldValue` objects. The new `CustomFieldValue` objects have set `custom_field_id`  to 1. This does not mean that Rails loads the custom_field object. This would only happen when you save the object and reload it. So `validates_presence_of :custom_field` is right to complain. This attribute is still nil. I think the same will happen for `custom_fieldable`

Comment: As far as I know, the custom_field_id is only 1 because the first custom field I created got ID 1, and when I created the view code, I had to put in a field for custom_field_id, otherwise the model would never know which field I was trying to set.

Comment: It's alright. But as far as I know Rails does not automaticaly load the dependent record. When you create a `CustomFieldValue` object and set `custom_field_value.custom_field_id = 1 ` then `custom_field_value.custom_field` is still nil. You can either execute `custom_field_value.save; custom_field_value.reload` to get `custom_field_value.custom_field` or `custom_field_value.custom_field = CustomField.find(1)`. I think when you simply reload your record after creation every thing is as you expect.

Comment: Actually on looking at the error message again, it isn't complaining about `custom_field`, but it's complaining about the `custom_fieldable`. So it's like it can't find the parent record. That is the kind of thing which I really think Rails itself should be doing for me when nested attributes are set, but maybe nested records never set a reference back to the parent automatically and I was just expecting Rails to be more convenient than it is?

Comment: `custom_fieldable` is a polymorphic association. So you have to set not only the `custom_fieldable_id` but also `custom_fieldable_type`. But I think your right, your expecting more magic as Rails is able to provide.

Comment: I'm not even setting `custom_fieldable_id `. For any other kind of association, Rails does that for me, so I expected it to work automatically here as well. The fact that it does work for update_attributes and not for the constructor is also a bit mysterious.  I wonder whether it's actually a bug...